# extract specific regression equation from a GAM model?

Tags: generalized-additive-model

Is it possible to extract the specific mathematical equation behind a best GAM model?

A generalized example: 
If for example I'm interested in regressing y ~ s(w,k=A) + s(x,k=A) + s(z,k=A)

and then predicting y based on the non-linear relationships of w, x and z. I know I can use the predict( ) function to come up with predictions, but I'm interested in a specific mathematical relationship (the splines) that best predict y (gaussian).

Perhaps this is an obvious question, if so, I apologize.

thanks